# ComicMind Material TextField Tint Color Not Changing

Tags: ios, cosmicmind

I've read the [guidelines for contributing of Cosmic Mind Material library for iOS](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md). I can't seem to change the tint color or the cursor of the TextField.

Here's my category code:

```
func setupCustomTextField(textColor: UIColor, placeHolder: String?, delegate: UITextFieldDelegate) -> TextField? {

    guard let materialSelf = self as? TextField else {
        return nil
    }

    materialSelf.backgroundColor = .clear
    materialSelf.textColor = textColor
    materialSelf.borderColor = textColor
    materialSelf.isClearIconButtonEnabled = true
    materialSelf.delegate = delegate
    materialSelf.dividerNormalColor = textColor
    materialSelf.dividerActiveColor = textColor
    materialSelf.tintColor = textColor
    materialSelf.font = R.font.latoRegular(size: 15)

    if let placeHolder = placeHolder {
        let localizedPlaceHolder = NSLocalizedString(placeHolder, comment: "")
        let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: localizedPlaceHolder,
                                                  attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor])
        materialSelf.attributedPlaceholder = attributedString
    }

    return materialSelf
}
```

And the result:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here are the properties you will want to change for coloring:

```
textField.placeholderNormalColor = Color.amber.darken4
textField.placeholderActiveColor = Color.pink.base
textField.dividerNormalColor = Color.cyan.base
textField.dividerActiveColor = Color.green.base
```

All the best :)